# Is there any way to reset the default option as "Current File" in "Replace" of WebStorm？

Tags: webstorm

Is there any way to reset the default option as "Current File" in "Replace" of WebStorm？

[image: Is there any way to reset the default option as "Current File" in "Replace" of WebStorm？]

Comment: Why do you need to use **"Replace in Files"** for the **current file**? Use normal in-file replace -- it does the same replacement.

Comment: Re the actual question: 1) you cannot set specific entry as a default; 2) The IDE will (should) remember the last option used on the next invocation; 3) Invoking this dialog from a folder context (e.g. from the Project View panel) will select that folder as an option instead of the previous one.

Comment: thank you :) the reason why I need it cause it'll be better for me to get a quick and entire view for the content I am searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to reset the default option as "Current File" in "Replace" of WebStorm？

You cannot.

1. You cannot set a specific entry as a default one.
2. The IDE will (should) remember the last option used when you invoke "Find/Replace in Files" next time.
3. If you invoke "Find/Replace in Files" from a folder context (e.g. from the Project View panel) then the IDE automatically will select that folder as an option instead of what you have there from the previous time.

> The reason why I need it cause it'll be better for me to get a quick and entire view for the content I am searching.

You can see the same "entre view" using in-file replace:

- There is an "Open in Find Tool Window" button in the search toolbar that will open ALL matches in a standard Find Results toolwindow (the same window that you get when you hit the "Open in Find Window" button in the bottom right of Find/Replace in Files). So ALL matches will be listed there;

  [image]
- the Preview area is also available (may need to enable it first -- there is a button for that). It also allows editing the file content right there.

  [image]